# Unable to understand the following error: "(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V" is not applicable on this object

Tags: java, resultset

When I am getting the result from the DB2 and trying to set to this attribute `noOfLocations` I am getting the following error.

```
Method "setNoOfLocations" with signature "(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V" is not applicable on this object
```

Following code shows the problem.

I am using rs to set the value.

```
packDO.setNoOfLocations(rs.getInt("NO_LOC_PKG"));
```

and

```
rs.getInt("NO_LOC_PKG") is returning 0
```

and

```
NO_LOC_PKG is of datatype Integer in the DB
```

and  `noOfLocations` type with setter method is,

```
private Integer noOfLocations;

public void setNoOfLocations(Integer noOfLocations) {
        this.noOfLocations = noOfLocations;
    }
```

Comment: Which Java version are you using?

Comment: Indeed, my guess is that you're using a version of Java which doesn't have autoboxing...

Comment: @Che: Are we correct in assuming that `rs` is a `java.sql.ResultSet`?

Comment: @JBNizet I am using `java 1.5` and the result set used is `java.sql.ResultSet`

Comment: @Che: Can you confirm that the line generating that error is indeed the line that you posted?

Comment: And is that a compilation error, or a runtime error? If it's a runtime error, post the full stack trace.

Comment: @JasonC yes it is .. I am running the code in the debug mode and after this it is not even going to the catch caluse but going directly to the finally block.

Comment: @Che: Are you sure that your build is up-to-date and that the source available to your debugger matches the source of the binary you are running?

Comment: @JB it is a runtime error.

Comment: @Jason Okay let me rebuild it again and let u knoo the updates. Thanks.

Comment: This is weird. Are you 100% positive that the setter code exists in the class of `packDO`?

Comment: @JasonC Awesome. It is a build issue. Can you pls put your comment as an answer. such that I can accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message you posted suggests that it's a build-related issue, as compiler and runtime errors don't generally describe methods by their signatures.

Make sure that your build is up-to-date and that the source available to your debugger matches the source of the binary you are running.

Depending on your build system, issues could result from previous partial builds, unexpected timestamps on files, copying/moving files, a crashed IDE, a quirky build system, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Autoboxing and unboxing is introduced in `Java 1.5.`

```
 int getInt(int columnIndex)
           throws SQLException
```

returns  `primitive`.

So if you are using <1.5 version java you will run into this issue.

Otherwise mention you verision.

Comment: I am using java 1.5 but still it seems an issue

Comment: Still the error suggests that there is no method with `Integer` argument. If this was an unboxing issue shouldn't the message say about `int`?

Comment: Hi NTR .. :) this is a build issue man. Anyways thanks for you suggesstions +1.

Comment: :)))) That's great You found  the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this and as other posters have described it refers to a class not being found at runtime. For me the reason is :

Within Eclipse I have a web app running on Tomcat. The web app refers to a seperate jar file that is also maintained within Eclipse. Within Eclipse everything is fine as the jar file is on the class path. However, when I attempt to use the web app which has a dependency on the jar file I receive this error. Tomcat is unable to find the jar file library. Fix : add relevant jar to build path of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ said, I think what you need is

```
packDO.setNoOfLocations( new Integer( rs.getInt("NO_LOC_PKG") ));
```

`getInt()` returns `int`, and `setNoOfLocations()` wants `java.lang.Integer`.

By the way, it has nothing to do with DB2.

Comment: This has nothing to do with boxing/autoboxing since I am using Java 1.5. As said by JasonC in the comment section this is a build issue.